# Why is my local variable null?

Tags: powershell

I'm working with a script for polling a folder. Once a file is dropped in this folder, an e-mail is sent to a recipient.

Here's the code:

```
$folder = "D:\\temptest"
$filter = "*.txt"

$fsw = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder, $filter -Property @{
    IncludeSubDirectories = $false
    NotifyFilter = [System.IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName, LastWrite'
}

$actionToRun = {
    $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
    $name = $Event.SourceVentArgs.Name
    $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
    $timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated

    Write-Host $name # --> Here $name contains the file name

    $Recipient = "Peter Rundqvist <to address>"
    $Sender = "SocSupport <from address>"
    $Subject = "New document"
    $Body = $name # --> But here, $name is null

    Send-MailMessage -To $Recipient -From $Sender -Subject $Subject -Body $Body  -SmtpServer "some mail server"
}

$onCreated = Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $fsw -EventName Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Action $actionToRun
```

Why is it that `$name` cannot be used as a parameter in the `Send-MailMessage` (it expands as null), whereas using it as a parameter in `Write-Host` works just fine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a typo, took me a good few runs to find it.

```
$name = $Event.SourceVentArgs.Name
```

Should be:

```
$name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name
```

It's hard to say why you might have ever had a value in $name to be able to write to the host.

Comment: Thanks, Chris! I don't know how I could have missed that... You saved my day!